# How to find basis of intersection of 2 vector spaces with given basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have vector spaces $\mathbb W$ and $\mathbb V$.

A given basis for $\mathbb W$ is $\{(1, 1, 0, -1), (0, 1, 3, 1)\}$,
and a given basis for $\mathbb V$ is $\{(1, 2, 2, -2), (0, 1, 2, -1)\}$.

How to find a basis for $\mathbb W\cap\mathbb V$?

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thank you for this comment. in fact, I have no idea how to try to solve this, thus, it didn't tried anything. moreover, I would like to get tutorial how to do o.

Comment: @user1798362 Can you find $\Bbb W \cap \Bbb V$? I mean the actual set, not a basis.

Comment: @GitGud I guess I do.

Comment: @user1798362 Start by findint, simplyfing the conditions that define the set and post your work on the question. Or just read the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any $\vec x\in\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W.$ Since $\vec x\in\Bbb V,$ then there exist unique scalars $\alpha,\beta$ such that $$\vec x=(\alpha,2\alpha+\beta,2\alpha+2\beta,-2\alpha-\beta).\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ Similarly, $\vec x\in\Bbb W,$ so there exist unique scalars $\gamma,\delta$ such that $$\vec x=(\gamma,\gamma+\delta,3\delta,-\gamma+\delta).\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$ By $(\clubsuit)$ and $(\diamondsuit),$ we have $$\begin{align}\vec 0 &= \vec x-\vec x\\ &= (\alpha-\gamma,2\alpha+\beta-\gamma-\delta,2\alpha+2\beta-3\delta,-2\alpha-\beta+\gamma-\delta).\end{align}\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ Since $0=\alpha-\gamma$ (why?) then $\gamma=\alpha,$ so replacing $\gamma$ with $\alpha$ in $(\heartsuit)$ gives us $$\begin{align}\vec 0 &= (\alpha-\alpha,2\alpha+\beta-\alpha-\delta,2\alpha+2\beta-3\delta,-2\alpha-\beta+\alpha-\delta)\\ &= (0,\alpha+\beta-\delta,2\alpha+2\beta-3\delta,-\alpha-\beta-\delta).\end{align}\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ Since $0=\alpha+\beta-\delta$ (why?), then $\delta=\alpha+\beta,$ so replacing $\delta$ with $\alpha+\beta$ in $(\spadesuit)$ gives us $$\begin{align}\vec 0 &= \bigl(0,\alpha+\beta-[\alpha+\beta],2\alpha+2\beta-3[\alpha+\beta],-\alpha-\beta-[\alpha+\beta]\bigr)\\ &= (0,0,-\alpha-\beta,-2\alpha-2\beta).\end{align}\tag{$*$}$$ Since $0=-\alpha-\beta$ (why?), then $\beta=-\alpha,$ and so replacing $\beta$ with $-\alpha$ in $(\clubsuit),$ we have $$\begin{align}\vec x &= \bigl(\alpha,2\alpha+[-\alpha],2\alpha+2[-\alpha],-2\alpha-[-\alpha]\bigr)\\ &= (\alpha,\alpha,0,-\alpha).\end{align}$$

Hence, every vector in $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ is a scalar multiple of $(1,1,0,-1).$

On the other hand, every scalar multiple of $(1,1,0,-1)$ is immediately in $\Bbb W$ since $(1,1,0,-1)$ is, and noting that $(1,1,0,-1)=(1,2,2,-2)-(0,1,2,-1)$, then $(1,1,0,-1)$ is in $\Bbb V$, as well, and so every scalar multiple of $(1,1,0,-1)$ is in $\Bbb V.$ Thus, every scalar multiple of $(1,1,0,-1)$ is a vector in $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W.$

By double inclusion, $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ is **precisely** the set of scalar multiples of $(1,1,0,-1),$ and so a convenient basis for $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ would be $$\bigl\{(1,1,0,-1)\bigr\}.$$

---

Let me sum up the general idea, here, so you can hopefully apply it in other cases. Let's suppose that we've got spaces $\Bbb V$ and $\Bbb W$ of dimension $m$ and $n,$ respectively--assume that $m\leq n$ without loss of generality--with given bases $\{\vec v_1,...,\vec v_m\}$ and $\{\vec w_1,...,\vec w_n\}$ (respectively).

$\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ is necessarily a subspace of $\Bbb V$ and of $\Bbb W.$ The idea, then, is to start with a general vector $\vec x$ in $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W,$ then write this as a general vector in $\Bbb V$ and as a general vector in $\Bbb W$--that is write $$\vec x=\alpha_1\vec v_1+\cdots\alpha_m\vec v_m\quad\text{ and }\quad \vec x=\beta_1\vec w_1+\cdots+\beta_n\vec w_n$$ for some unique scalar $\alpha_i$s and $\beta_j$s.

Now, since $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb V$, then it has dimension of **at most** $m$, so we'll be able to eliminate most of the scalars by setting $$\vec0=\left(\alpha_1\vec v_1+\cdots\alpha_m\vec v_m\right)-\left(\beta_1\vec w_1+\cdots+\beta_n\vec w_n\right),\tag{#}$$ then repeatedly back-substituting as above. In particular, we'll be able to eliminate **all** of the $\beta_j$s (since we assumed $m\leq n$), and once we've done that, we'll want to eliminate as many of the $\alpha_i$s as possible.

At some point, if we keep substituting into the chain of vector equations that started with $(\#)$, then we *may* end up with the equation $\vec 0=\vec 0$. For example, if we'd substituted $\beta=-\alpha$ into $(*)$ above, that's what we'd get. If that happens, we'll know we've reduced as far as we can, and we'll want to use the relationships we've determined between the various $\alpha_i$s along the way to rewrite $x$ in terms of as few $\alpha_i$s as possible--that's what we did above when we subbed back into $(\clubsuit)$--and that will show that every vector in $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$ can be written as a linear combination of some vectors, which should comprise the basis for $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W$. (It's worth checking, of course.) Consider the spaces $\Bbb V$ and $\Bbb W$ with respective bases $$\{(1,0,0,0),(1,2,2,-2),(0,1,2,-1)\}$$ and $$\{(0,1,0,-1),(1,1,0,-1),(0,1,3,1)\}$$ for an example where we still have more than one $\alpha_i$ left at the end, and see if you can pick out appropriate basis vectors in that case.

Now, it *might* be that we end up discovering that all the $\alpha_i$s are $0$. In that case, $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W=\{\vec 0\}$, and the basis is the empty set. Consider for example the spaces $\Bbb V$ and $\Bbb W$ with respective bases $\{(1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,-1)\}$ to see how this can happen.

Comment: Thank you but I have question - 
"Since 0=−α−β (why?), then β=−α, and so replacing β with −α, we have" - How did you got from 

"(0,0,−α−β,−2α−2β)" to "(α,α,0,−α)"? the 2 first vector wasn't being 0?

Comment: Notice **which** vector I made that substitution in. The first two I made the substitution in $0=x-x$, but not that one.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: I made the last substitution into $x$, not $0=x-x$. We had $$x=(\alpha,2\alpha+\beta,2\alpha+2\beta,-2\alpha-\beta),\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ yes? Once we found out that we needed $\beta=-\alpha,$ we were able to rewrite $x$ in terms of $\alpha$ **only** by substituting $-\alpha$ for $\beta$ in $(\clubsuit).$ Do you see it now?

Comment: You'd better highlight it in your answer .. It wasn't clear. But now it is. Great. thank you very much.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make that clearer. Also, I have given the general principle that this answer takes, so you can apply it in other situations. Take a read through and see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: OK, I just got it . So, are you just trying to get simpler expression of `a` and `b` and plug it into one of the given basis?

Comment: Pretty much. Once we eliminate as many extraneous $\alpha_i$s as possible, the number of remaining $\alpha_i$s in the new expression for $\vec x$ (once we sub in and simplify) will be the dimension of $\Bbb V\cap\Bbb W.$ Were you able to get through the examples I gave you?

Comment: I was. You gave me a great explanation .. I've just got a bit confused at first look. but it great. should I say thanks over again? :-) Cause I just owe you.

Comment: Good. Just wanted to make sure you had a decent general grasp of the idea, instead of just how this problem worked. Always glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb W \cap \mathbb V$ is either $\mathbb W (=\mathbb V)$, a line that is common to the two, or just the origin.  If the two spaces are the same, you can express both basis vectors of one in terms of the vectors of the other.  So write $(1,1,0,-1)=a(1,2,2,-2)+b(0,1,2,-1)$, then for the other.  If you can find $a$ and $b$ the spaces are the same and either of the bases you have will work.  If not, try to find a vector in the intersection by writing $c(1,1,0,-1)+d(0,1,3,1)=a(1,2,2,-2)+b(0,1,2,-1)$ and see if you can find a solution.  If so, the vector that is the solution is a basis.  Else the intersection is only the origin, which has no basis.